# JMenuItems on a JPopupMenu sometimes aren't drawn

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

I have a JPopupMenu that is displayed when a JButton is held down. This menu contains a series of JMenuItems, each associated with an action, that change sometimes. The problem I'm having is that intermitently the JMenuItems aren't being drawn, I simply get a grey JPopupMenu, but the items appear if I move the mouse cursor over them. I thought the problem might be with not properly repainting the components after changes, but testing show the problem keeps happening even when there are no changes to the items. Here is the relevant code:

```
    if (!listChanged) {
        myPopupMenu.show(myButton, x, y);
    } else {
        List<String> menuList = getMenuList();
        MyData data = getData();
        myPopupMenu.removeAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuList.size(); i++) {
            String name = menuList.get(i);
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new MyMenuAction(this, name,
                    data, i));
            item.addActionListener(this);
            myPopupMenu.add(item);
            myPopupMenu.validate();
        }
        myPopupMenu.repaint();
        myPopupMenu.show(myButton, x, y);
    }
...

private static class MyMenuAction extends AbstractAction {
    private MyClass parent;
    private int index;
    private MyData data;

    public MyMenuAction (MyClass parent, String name,
            MyData data, int index) {
        super(name);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.index = index;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object[] actionParameters;
        try {
            actionParameters = data.getParameters(index);
        } catch (ImmediateException e1) {
            log(e1.getMessage(), "Error");
            return;
        }
        parent.myButtonAction(actionParameters);
    }

}
```

Just to clarify, the actions are working fine and 8 times out of 10 the JPopupMenu and all the JMenuItems are drawn right, but I can't figure out why they don't appear sometimes (regardless of whether the list has changed or not). Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok, following Andrew Thompson's recomendation, here is a short complete example. Many of the methods have been striped bare, but the basic is still there. Just click and hold the button "SHOW MENU" to display the JPopupMenu. Since the problem is intermitent, it may be necessary to do it several times until the problem occurs.

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyClass implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    boolean listChanged = true;
    boolean mousePressed = false;
    long clickStart;
    JPopupMenu myPopupMenu;
    JButton myButton;
    JFrame myFrame;
    ArrayList<String> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }

        startList();
        myButton = new JButton("SHOW MENU");
        myPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.add(new JButton("Button1"));
        toolbar.add(new JButton("Button2"));
        toolbar.add(new JButton("Button3"));
        toolbar.add(new JButton("Button4"));
        toolbar.add(new JButton("Button5"));
        toolbar.add(myButton);

        myButton.addMouseListener(this);

        toolbar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
        JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();

        myFrame.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        myFrame.add(emptyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setExtendedState(myFrame.getExtendedState()
                | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void showMenu() {
        if (!listChanged) {
            myPopupMenu.show(myButton, 0, myButton.getHeight());
        } else {
            listChanged = false;
            List<String> menuList = getMenuList();
            MyData data = getData();
            myPopupMenu.removeAll();

            for (int i = 0; i < menuList.size(); i++) {
                String name = menuList.get(i);
                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new MyMenuAction(this, name,
                        data, i));
                item.addActionListener(this);
                myPopupMenu.add(item);
                myPopupMenu.validate();
            }
            myPopupMenu.repaint();
            myPopupMenu.show(myButton, 0, myButton.getHeight());
        }
    }

    private void startList() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");
        list.add("Item 5");
    }

    private List<String> getMenuList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void myButtonAction() {
        Object[] defaultParameters = getDefaultParameters();
        myButtonAction(defaultParameters);
    }

    private Object[] getDefaultParameters() {
        // Placeholder
        return null;
    }

    public void myButtonAction(Object[] actionParameters) {
        // Placeholder
    }

    private MyData getData() {
        // Placeholder
        return new MyData();
    }

    private void changeList(List<String> newList) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(newList);
        listChanged = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Placeholder
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == myButton) {
            mousePressed = true;
            clickStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (mousePressed)
                            try {
                                this.wait(10);
                                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - clickStart > 300) {
                                    MyClass.this.showMenu();
                                    return;
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                break;
                            }
                        MyClass.this.myButtonAction();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static class MyData {

        public Object[] getParameters(int index) {
            // Placeholder
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static class MyMenuAction extends AbstractAction {
        private MyClass parent;
        private int index;
        private MyData data;

        public MyMenuAction(MyClass parent, String name, MyData data, int index) {
            super(name);
            this.parent = parent;
            this.index = index;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object[] actionParameters;
            try {
                actionParameters = data.getParameters(index);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            parent.myButtonAction(actionParameters);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _Sometimes?_ See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and consider `setComponentPopupMenu()`.

Comment: *"Here is the relevant code:"*  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @trashgod I do have a thread on my mouse listener, because it is only supposed to show the JPopupMenu if I hold it down for a while (if I just click, it performs a simpler action), but I don't understand how that could cause my problem, since the menu is displayed, but only the JMenuItems aren't drawn.

Comment: `I do have a thread on my mouse listener,` - then maybe the mouse listener is the problem. Do you realized that a mouseClick is only generated when a mousePressed and mouseReleased event is generated at the same location. So if while you hold the mouse down for a period of time and the mouse moves a single pixel you will not get a mouseClicked event. This could be why it is random. So basically the code you posted is (potentially) irrelevant to the problem. That is why a runnable example as requested by Andres should be posted with every question.

Comment: @camickr I already did, I edited my question just before replying to trashgod

Comment: @FredLage, sorry I missed that. Guess I didn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a JPopupMenu that is displayed when a JButton is held down.

First of all I have a problem with a UI like that. The standard is to show a popup when you right click (in windows). Follow known standards. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more information and working examples.

Secondly, I can't reproduce the problem (no matter how long I try). Random problems are usually caused by the GUI not being updated on the EDT. So don't use a Thread.

Instead use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Set the `Timer` to fire after 200ms at which time you display the menu. Code executed from the Timer IS invoked on the EDT. So you would `restart()` the `Timer` in `mousePressed`. and `stop()` the `Timer` in `mouseReleased`.

Comment: I can't really use a different behavior (right click for pop up) because this is for work and I've got to follow what is required. I was told the reason was that they wanted it to function like the back button on web browsers, where clicking once takes you to the last page and holding shows a history of the last pages. I will try changing to use a Timer though and see if it works

Comment: `I was told the reason was that they wanted it to function like the back button on web browsers, where clicking once takes you to the last page and holding shows a history of the last pages.` - interesting, I never knew that functionality existed. I always just use right click to get the history. I guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: Adding a Timer seems to have resolved the problem, so thanks @camickr. Still, I don't understand the underlying cause of this issue. If anyone could explain why would the code work so far as drawing the JPopupMenu, but not its JMenuItems, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @FredLage, It's a threading issue. I don't know the details of why things sometimes work and sometimes they don't work. The point is all GUI components should be created and updated on the EDT (or you can have random problems). This is a rule that should always be followed so you don't spend time chasing random problems :) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.